# Force expand menus in Drupal 7 (port from Drupal 6)

Tags: php, drupal, templates, menu, drupal-7

In D6 you can use the following code in your template.php to force expand menus:

```
function menu_tree_full($menu_name = 'navigation') {
  static $menu_output = array();
  if (!isset($menu_output[$menu_name])) {
    $tree = menu_tree_all_data($menu_name);
    $menu_output[$menu_name] = menu_tree_output($tree);
  }
  return $menu_output[$menu_name];
}
```

You then place the following in your page.tpl.php:

```
print menu_tree_full('navigation');
```

Can anyone advise me how to port this to D7? In particular force expanding the 'management' menu.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Administration » Structure » Menus - then click on operations on the tree you want and choose expanded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Drupal 7 has changed its API for the function menu_tree_all_data(), you may want to read into it here:

[Drupal API 7, menu_tree_all_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data)

Comment: Also: Function names in the file template.php must now use the relevant theme's name. It is mentioned here: [link](http://drupal.org/node/254940)